# Create parameterizable map between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: functions

I would like to create a parameterizable map between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$.  This map I'll call $M$ and the parameter I'll call $k$.  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (but if there is a better space for $k$, I'm open to suggestions)

- $M(z, k) \rightarrow (x, y)$
- $M^{-1}(x, y, k) \rightarrow z$

The requirements for $M$:

- $M$ and $M^{-1}$ are defined for all values in their domains
- For any $(x,y)$ there exists at least one set of values for $z$ and $k$ such that $M(z, k) = (x, y)$

### My project

(for those who care about why I want to do this)

I'm a computer programmer, and I'm working on a side project (for fun).  My idea is that I want to build a model of an "entity" inside of an "environment".

**Entity**

- Input: $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}, [0,1]$
- Output: $z' = z + \Delta z$

$\Delta z$ is calculated based on an internal algorithm that isn't important to the question.

**Environment**

- Internal State: $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$
- Input (Output From Entity): $z'$
- Output (Input To Entity): $M^{-1}(M(z',k),k) = z$ and $c = e^{-|M(z',k)-p*|}$

** $p*$ is the "most content" state of the environment ($p* = (x*,y*)).

** |...| denotes a distance measurement

Note that $c$ can be any mapping between $[0, \infty] \rightarrow [1, 0]$ (sorry if that notation isn't conventional... 0 maps to 1, and $\infty$ maps to 0... and monotonically decreasing).

The goal of my project is to build an entity to search it's own internal state-space to maximize the contentment value ($c$) it receives from the environment... but it receives a $\mathbb{Z}$ input and it's trying to find the output which maps to a specific value in environment's internal $\mathbb{Z}^2$ space... how it does this will depend on $M$, but I'm confident that I can solve that part if I can find an appropriate (hopefully non-trivial) $M$.

The function $M^{-1}(x,y,k)$ maps a point $(x,y)$ to an integer $z$ which is input to the entity.  In a more "real" model, this would be like the entity's "perspective" of the environment. $k$ in my mind acts like a *key*, and the entity needs to find the key in order to "solve" the environment to achieve maximum contentment.

My motivation and why I think this is interesting is that any environment that an entity "lives in" has more state than the possible perceptions that an entity has of that environment.  This is a naive attempt to model that observation.  In the future, I'd look to combine multiple entities which are able to "solve" this $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2$ environment setup to "solve" generally an environment setup of $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^m$

### Attempts to solve the problem

My idea was that I needed some set of hashing functions $H_1$ and $H_2$ which act as an operator between two values in $\mathbb{Z}$.  The two functions I'd need are $H_1(z,k) = x$ and $H_2(z,k) = y$.  Then, I'd need to create inverse functions so that $M(H_1^{-1}(x,k), H_2^{-1}(y,k), k) = z$.

In my existing simulation, I only require one hash from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ and there is no $k$.  Introducing $k$ was tricky to me and I didn't see an obvious way to do it.

Comment: Are $x,y,z,k$ fixed or variable? Also, please provide some context.

Comment: Also what set is $\mathbb{I}$ here? The integers? (usually denoted $\mathbb{Z}$...)

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for that. Edited. Also, is there any way I could make this question not off-topic?

Comment: @JohnCarpenter You could delete this one and then repost the question, but you will have to fix what was wrong with this one first because otherwise it will probably be closed again for the same reasons.  (I don't know what those are, and no one bothered to let you know, either.)

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Add some context, i.e. why is this question interesting, and include your attempts to solve this problem in the question.

Comment: @Hetebri, thanks. Will do :)

Comment: For example $F(x,y,k)=2x-5y-k$ along with $G(z,k)=3z+3k$ ans $H(z,k)=z+k$ satisfy the two notes, and that $F(G(z,k),H(z,k),k)=z$ for all values of $z,k.$ Is this the kind of solution wanted, wherein $x,y$ are just temporary names for the outputs of $G,H$? [Explaining that would improve the question]

Answer (score 1):

You can define $M_0$ to be a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}^2$, and then define $M_k(z)=M_0(z+k)$.

For $M_0$ define $M_0(0)=(0,0)$, and for $z\neq0$, $M_0(z)=f\mathopen{}\left(\left\lvert2z\right\rvert-\frac{z}{2\left\lvert z\right\rvert}-\frac12\right)\mathclose{}$ where $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ defined below.

$f$ maps $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ by walking concentric diamonds around the origin. These diamonds have perimeters $4,8,12,16,\ldots$, so $f$ will take $z$ and decide which set $z$ is in from $\{1,\ldots,4\},\{5,\ldots,12\},\{13,\ldots,24\},\{25,\ldots,40\}$, etc. Then it will decide on which edge of the diamond $f(m)$ should lie. Here is how that formula looks.

Define some auxiliary variables $n=\left\lceil\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+2m}}{2}\right\rceil$ (providing us with the $n$th concentric diamond that $f(m)$ lives in), $u=m-(2(n-1)^2+2(n-1))$ (the index of $f(m)$ in the counterclockwise tracing out of the integer points in the $n$th diamond), and $w=\left\lceil\frac{u}{n}\right\rceil$ (telling is which of the four edges $f(m)$ lives in).

And we have $$f(m)=\delta_{w=1}(n+1-u,u-1)+\delta_{w=2}(n+1-u,2n+1-u)+\delta_{w=3}(u-3n-1,2n+1-u)+\delta_{w=4}(u-3n-1,u-4n-1)$$

So here is an example: find $M_3(96)$. This is $M_0(99)$. Which is $f(197)$. With $z=197$, we have $n=10$, $u=17$, and $w=2$. So $f(197)=(10+1-17,20+1-17)=(-6,4)$.

I think it wouldn't be impossible to write an explicit inverse formula for $M_0$, but I'm out of steam to actually think it through. As an outline, first you would identify which quadrant $(x,y)$ is in (counting axis rays as part of the quadrant that is clockwise to them). Then determine which line (having slope $\pm1$) that $(x,y)$ lies on. Then use that line's intercepts to determine which $n$th diamond $(x,y)$ is on. Use that to determine which block $\{1,\ldots,4\},\{5,\ldots,12\},\{13,\ldots,24\},\{25,\ldots,40\}$, etc. that $M_{-1}(x,y)$ lives in. And a few more details to settle on what $M^{-1}(x,y)$ actually is within that block.